# In linux asynchronous serial port programming how to distinguish read and write

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, serial-port

I am implementing a linux application with a serial interface. I am using signal mechanism to make it asynchronous.

```
saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
```

I am reading the received data in the signal handler itself and its working. As I need to respond very fast, I  have some more logic implemented in the signal handler. So the signal handler is not very small.

The problem is that when I am trying to write to the serial port, the signal handler is getting called again. I do not want this. Is it possible to use the signal handler only for received data.

Or is it possible to distinguish between reception and transmission in the signal handler?

Kiran

Comment: how about creating a structure which you will modify if you write or read data. This way inside your handler you can use if() function and you will only execute it under conditions you want.

Comment: Why are you using signals? The usual method using `select()` etc. works faultlessly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the signal handler only for received data.

If you insist on using signals for the task, it is of course possible by letting the part of your software which generates the signals generate no or another signal for transmitted data.

Answer (score 0):

while you're configuring your signal handler, you can add the following flag to your sa_flags in the saio  sigaction structure:

```
saio.sa_flags |= SA_SIGINFO;
```

when you configure this flag, your function signal_handler_IO will need 3 parameters:

```
void signal_handler_IO (int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
```

then the structure siginfo_t will contain the information needed to understand the signal that caused the interruption.